# Unwanted destructor call in std::swap

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, move

I've run into a problem with std::swap.  I have to swap an object.  That object releases memory in its destructor.  I've written a move constructor and a move assignment operator that copies the pointer to that memory.  The default constructor sets that pointer to NULL.

Of course, I have a regular copy constructor and assignment operator, but they allocate and copy the memory, which is obviously not what I want for my swap operation.

When I call std::swap, it creates a temporary object from _Left using my move constructor.  Then, it uses my move assignment operator to move _Right to _Left, and finally, it moves the temp object to _Right.

This all looks good when you get to the bottom of std::swap.  However, when you step out of the bottom of it, the destructor for the temp object runs, freeing the memory that the _Right object is expecting to have.

What's the normal accepted way to do this?  I was hoping to avoid having to write swap functions since that's the point of move constructors/move assignment operators.  Do I have to use my own swap() to avoid this?

Comment: Show your implementation.

Comment: Showing us your move special member function implementations would've been a lot easier than writing several paragraphs about the problem. Anyway, it sounds like you're not setting the pointer in source object to `nullptr` after moving from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after a lot more study, I understand my fundamental problem and the solution.

**Short Version:**
In your move constructor, copy values from the source object, then set them to the value they would be if your default constructor had run.

**Long Version:**
When you create a move constructor or move assignment operator, you must leave the object being assigned from in a default state that can be destructed.  Swapping does not accomplish this.  Instead, you need to first steal the resources from the source object, then set the members of the source object to the state they would be in if a constructor had run.

One example where swapping lands you in hot water is where you're dealing with a pointer, like I was.  You can't copy or swap it.  If you copy the pointer, then the pointer value will still be in the source object when it gets destructed.  If you swap the pointer, then it will be an uninitialized value, which will probably crash your destructor. Instead, you should copy the pointer value, then set the pointer in the source object to NULL.  Of course, you must check for NULL in destructors when releasing memory.

If one of the members you're stealing is a class instance you control, then you should use std::move to copy it, since that will invoke its move assignment operator, also leaving it destructable.

**Bonus**:
Don't reinvent the wheel.  Just invoke your move assignment operator from your move constructor.

```
void CObject::CObject(CObject&& other)
{
    *this = std::move(other);
}
CObject& CObject::operator = (CObject&& other)
{
    // m_pResource is a pointer.
    // Copy the value.
    m_pResource = other.m_pResource;
    // Set other to default state so the destructor doesn't free it.
    other.m_pResource = NULL;

    // m_iCount is an int who's value does not matter in the destructor.
    m_iCount = other.m_iCount;

    // m_Obj is a class instance.
    // Invoking move semantics will use its move assignment operator if it has one.
    m_Obj = std::move(other.m_Obj);

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: "you must check for NULL in destructors when releasing memory", no delete nullptr; is fine

Comment: You're right that you can call delete/free on a null pointer.  However, if you're doing anything more than that to release resources, then it makes sense to just do the check.  To me, it just feels better.

Answer (score 4):

The move operation should leave the object being moved from in a destructible state, which may be a different state than how it came into the move.

If I am understanding the problem right it sounds like your object's move-ctor needs to set the pointer(s) in the object being moved from to something other than the values they came in with. A subsequent dtor on those now-moved objects should leave the memory they once referred to alone.

Comment: Isn't it *unspecified* state rather than *destructible*?

Comment: @remyabel: To be in any way usable, the state must be "unspecified but valid", where "valid" means, at the very least, "destructible". All standard library types give this guarantee; user-defined type that don't can't generally be safely moved from.